# How to make a rule for a set of combined reducers in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have two standard reducers that both look like this

**Reducer1**

```
const reducer1 = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case('clear'):
      return {
        ...state,
        reducer1property1: null
      }
    ...<other cases>...
  }
}
```

**Reducer2**

```
const reducer2 = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case('clear'):
      return {
        ...state,
        reducer2property1: null
      }
    ...<other cases>...
  }
}
```

So if I dispatch an action of type 'clear', then property1 will get cleared in both reducers.

I combine the reducers like this:

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  Reducer1,
  Reducer2
})
```

My question is: is there a way to do this without writing the 'clear' case in each reducer separately? For instance, is there a way to add the 'clear' case onto `combinedReducer` so that I can write it only once? In my actual app there are many more reducers, so I'm looking to simplify.

Thanks!

Comment: What are reducer1property1 and reducer1property2? Are they reducer names or some random keys? The code isn't repeated. It depends on reducer1property1, etc. *then property1 will get cleared in both reducers.* - so is it property1 or reducer1property1?

Answer (score 2):

This is where the concept of a "higher order reducer" comes in.  If the functionality is common, write it once, and use that reducer to "wrap" any other reducers that need that behavior.  In your case, something like:

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer1 : closeable(reducer1),
    reducer2 : closeable(reducer2),
});
```

See the [Redux Docs page on "Reusing Reducer Logic"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) , this slideshow on [The Power of Higher Order Reducers](http://slides.com/omnidan/hor#/), and some of these other articles on [Redux Reducers and Selectors](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-reducers-selectors.md) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

No. Combine reducer receives only reducers.

Since every reducer is in charge of a different slice of the state if you want the "clear" action to apply to all reducers you have to treat it in all of them.

Comment: just an addition: found old and interesting discussion on that https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/601 also there are few libraries mentioned like `reduce-reducers` that may change the way we usually structure store/reducers